# Output the text

Tags: oracle, text

Is there a way i can output in SQL Oracle as follow with a single quote at the beginning and end, plus a comma (,). Many thanks in advance!

original output:

```
Number
0910000001
0910000002
0910000003
0910000004
0910000018
0910000019
0910000020
```

Desired output:

```
Number
'0910000001',
'0910000002',
'0910000003',
'0910000004',
'0910000018',
'0910000019',
'0910000020',
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to just add it you your query...

select ''' + number + ''' , ' ' as trailing_comma from table..

the second `' '` is so your output will insert a comma after your `'Number'`

Comment: +1 More-or-less correct for SQLServer, as originally requested. Oracle uses `||` for string concatenation instead of `+`, so the equivalent query should be `select '''' || number || ''', ' as trailing_comma from table`.